# Что означают знаки : | и &, в Python

Tags: python

Пожалуйста объясните что делают выше приведенные знаки, и если есть возможность то с **примерами**

Answer (score 0):

Это побитовое сложение(или) и умножение(и).

```
0b1 | 0b10 == 0b11
0b1 & 0b10 == 0b0
```

Есть ещё исключающее или ‘^‘